# Terraform 0.11: Not able to add dynamic security group to aws instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, terraform, infrastructure-as-code, terraform0.11

In the ec2 instance module I have couple of security groups one from variable and other created in the module. I have a situation where new security groups are to be added in the terraform file which are sourcing from this module.

To be able to concat a new list I want to convert existing format1 into an explicit list which I am not able to do. How can I achieve this?

```
resource "aws_instance" "instance" {
//...
# (current)format1: Works
vpc_security_group_ids = ["${aws_security_group.secGrp_1.id}", "${var.secGrp_2}"] 

# format2: Doesn't work
vpc_security_group_ids = "${list(aws_security_group.secGrp_1.id, var.secGrp_2)}"

# format3: Works
vpc_security_group_ids = "${list(var.secGrp_2)}"

# format3: Doesn't works
vpc_security_group_ids = "${list(tostring(aws_security_group.secGrp_1.id), var.secGrp_2)}"
```

Format2 fails with: "vpc_security_group_ids: should be a list".
I suspect the secGrp1 id is not being recognized as a string in this representation.

Format4 fails with: "unknown function called: tostring in:
${(list(tostring(aws_security_group.secGrp_1.id), var.secGrp_2))}"

P.S: The Terraform version we are using is 0.11.x

Comment: 0.11 is very, very old. Its better to upgrade, as you will be have more and more issues with it

Comment: @Marcin, thats in the pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

Terraform v0.11 is unable to represent partially-unknown lists during expression evaluation. On initial create, `aws_security_group.secGrp_1.id` will be unknown and therefore passing it to the `list` function will produce a wholly-unknown value, which isn't valid to use as the value for a list argument.

This is one of the various expression-language-related problems that Terraform v0.12 addressed. In Terraform v0.12 the following expression equivalent to your second one should work:

```
  vpc_security_group_ids = [
    aws_security_group.secGrp_1.id,
    var.secGrp_2,
  ]
```

To get your intended result with Terraform v0.11 will require applying this configuration in two stages, so that Terraform can know the value of `aws_security_group.secGrp_1.id` before evaluating `aws_instance.instance`:

1. `terraform apply -target=aws_security_group.secGrp_1` to apply only that resource and the other resources it depends on.
2. Then just `terraform apply` to apply everything else, including `aws_instance.instance`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Somehow this format ["${list(aws_security_group.secGrp_1.id, var.secGrp_2)}"] (adding square brackets ) worked.